# Angular 4/ Typescript - Delete number of rows selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my application I am looking for writing a function that deletes the number of check boxes selected from my array. I have written and i can console.log the the number of checkboxes i have selected. But im stuck at how to get index numbers of the selected check boxes and delete those only. And in delete function i have to spilce those number of rows from main array.

html -

```
     <ng-container *ngFor="let reasoncode of displayReasonCodes$ | async;let i = index">
    <tr class= "row-break">
    <checkbox type="checkbox"  name="sizecb[]" value="{{reasoncode.id}}"  [(ngModel)]="reasoncode.state">
      </checkbox>
      <td>  
      <form>
    <form-group>
    <textbox [readOnly]="isEditable" ngModel="{{reasoncode.ReasonCode}}"  name="textbox" ></textbox>
    </form-group>
    </form>
    </td>
    <td>
    <form>
     <form-group>
    <textbox  [readOnly]="isEditable" ngModel="{{reasoncode.Description}}" name="textbox1" ></atextbox>
    </form-group>
    </form>
    </td>
    <form>
    <p>
    <toggle-switch   ngModel="{{reasoncode.Status}}"   name="switch1"  ></toggle-switch>
    </p>
    </form>
    </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
export class ReasonCodesComponent implements OnInit {


    checkAll(event: any) {
      if (!this.result) return;
      this.result.forEach((x: any) => x.state = event.target.checked)
      }

     isAllChecked() {
      if (this.arr) return;
      return this.result.every((_: any) => _.state);
      }
     check(result: any) {
     result.state == false;
      result.state! = result.state;
      }
    @select(store.displayReasonCodes) displayReasonCodes$: Observable<IReasonCodes>;

      arr: any[];
      state: any;
      $event: any;
      displayReasonCodes: any;
      x: any;
      _: any;
      result: any;
      isEditable: boolean;

     constructor(private reasonCodesActions: ReasonCodesActions) {
      }

      reasoncodeObject:Object;
      ngOnInit() {

    this.displayReasonCodes$.subscribe(data => this.result = data ) 
      }

    deleterow() { 
        this.result.forEach((x: any) => {
          if (x.state) {  alert(x.state)  /// here i am getting true as alert for number of rows selected and when i clcik on delete.

            let copyObj = this.displayReasonCodes$.subscribe(data1=>this.data=(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data1))));

            console.log(this.data)  ; //data contains the array of objects, from which i have to splice up the number of selected rows from table.

          };
        })
      }

    }
```

I am looking for to delete the rows selected in checkbox and display the rest ones left out.

Answer (score 1):

As you define your field state with 'any' instead of 'boolean' try this. Just leave out those objects that are checked, return those that are unchecked:

```
this.result = this.result.filter(el => {
    el.state == undefined || el.state == null || el.state == false;
});
```

Put this code instead of your forEach()-loop in your deleterow()-method.

Comment: @DabolicWords nope its not returning me anything!!

Comment: What's the state of your checkboxes? Is there at least one that is not selected?

Comment: initially all o them are unselected

Comment: i tried new code, it does not return anything. and by clicking on any row checkbox it seletcs top row check as well. that i dont need in my use case.

Comment: i am looking for a function that works with my checkbox selection to return the rows seleted with their indexes, so then i can do whatever i want like delete.

Comment: If you want to delete checked rows, use my function above. If you want to manipulate content of those selected boxes use your forEach()-loop. That's the only hint I can give you up to here. Please note, that I reworked my answer once more.

Comment: DiabolicWords - i got you, but how can i see the checked rows array i am getting so then i cn perform some operation on it.?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/7l4AltdWfLGdLaXgF4vl?p=preview plz see this example, i have used this in amy application and i am looking for delete to work for number of rows selected.

Comment: right now its returning array with null values, even after i select multiple checkboxes

Comment: @user8819437: I've added a second answer, considering your latest entries and the plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I see. Having your code on Plunkr as source I did the following, just to show you how it works:

In your template I changed

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}" [(ngModel)]="size.state" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" (change)="checkOccurred()" value="{{size.id}}" [(ngModel)]="size.state" />
```

Next I extended your sizes-object only to broaden the variety of the possible output:

```
sizes: any[] = [
    { 'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km', 'state': false },
    { 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km', 'state': false },
    { 'size': '23', 'diameter': '3000 km', 'state': false },
    { 'size': '22', 'diameter': '700 km', 'state': false },
    { 'size': '99', 'diameter': '377000 km', 'state': false }
];
```

Please note, that I applied the missing field 'state', which makes every action much easier afterwards.

Then I added the following 2 methods

```
private checkOccurred(): void {
    this.getSelectedCheckboxes();
}

private getSelectedCheckboxes(): any[] {
    const result: number[] = [];

    this.sizes.forEach((item, index) => {

        if (item.state === true) {
            result.push(index);
        }
    });

    console.log(result);

    return result;
}
```

What you see here considering getSelectedCheckboxes() is exactly what you want. A method that delivers a list of the indexes of the selected checkboxes in your array states.

Hope this helps.